# How can I connect and Store results into table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar.io and have allowed users to be able to select an event and it posts successfully to the webpage. Below is the code for the calendar logic.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'interaction' ],

    //Behavior of calendar object
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    unselectAuto: true,
    eventLimit: true,

    header:
    {
      left: 'prevYear,prev',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'next,nextYear'
    },

    footer:
    {
      center: 'today'
    },

    //Logic for clicking on a date
    dateClick: function(event_click)
    {
      var event_name = prompt("Enter a title for this event", "New Event");

      //Add event to the calendar
      calendar.addEvent({

        title: event_name,
        start: event_click.date,
        allDay: true
      });
    },

    //Logic for clicking on an event
    eventClick: function(event_click)
    {
      alert(event_click.event.title + ' event removed'),
      //Remove event from calendar
      event_click.remove(),
      calendar.render()
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

I also have a php file that connects to a database and has an insert statement shown below.

```
<?php

$server_name = "localhost";
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root'
$db_name = 'testCalendardb';
$table_name = 'Event';

//Opens connection to the db
function openConn()
{
  try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server_name;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected to DB";

    return $conn;
  } catch(PDOException $exception) {
    echo "Connection Failed: Error: ".$exception->getMessage();
  }
}

function insert($date, $name) {
  try {
    $conn = openConn();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name(date, name) VALUES (:date, :name)";

    $sql->bindParam(':date', $date);
    $sql->bindParam(':name', $name);

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New Record Added";
  } catch(PDOException $exception) {
    echo $sql."<br>".$exception->getMessage();
  }
} 

//Closes the door
function closeConn($conn)
{
  $conn = null;
}

?>
```

My problem is I am having great difficulty trying to store the events inside of the mysql database. I have looked at many tutorials online, and I have the foundation to do web development. I feel like I am missing a step to actually send the data to the database that I cannot find in any tutorial. The tutorials i do use are out of date and don't really apply to the up-to-date versions of mysql/php/js.

To summarize, How can i use my php script to insert events into my database?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You want to use [`prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [`execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) instead of `exec()`

Comment: `$table_name` is not defined in the scope of `insert`

Comment: Where and how do you call your PHP functions?

Comment: I was trying to call them from the javascript file but I know that is wrong. I then assumed I would call them from the html file, but I'm not sure how to get the data I need from the js file back to the html file

Comment: An issue addressed in one of the answers below: this is not a production level development. I will worry about security flaws and the like once I actually am able to use the database.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you'll want to create an AJAX script to send data to your php file.
Something like:

```
//jquery required for this approach
$.ajax({
  url: 'add_events.php',
  data: 'event_name='+ title+'&event_date='+ start2 +'&event_end='+ end2,                                                    
  type: "POST"
});
```

Then in your php file you can add this to get the data stored in php variables:

```
$event_date = $_GET['event_date'];
$event_name = $_GET['event_name'];
```

Then your function becomes something like:

```
function insert() {
      try {
        $table_name = 'Event';
        $conn = openConn();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name(date, name) VALUES ($event_date, $event_name)";

        $conn->execute($sql);
        echo "New Record Added";
      } catch(PDOException $exception) {
        echo $sql."<br>".$exception->getMessage();
      }
}
insert();
```

Hope this helps or helps get you on the right track.

*edited to include function calls and address typo and other issues pointed out by Dharman.

**Also
Looking over the javascript, it looks like you have code to delete an event as well. You will also need to add an ajax request to look up and delete the row for any created event.
I would recommend having the Event table structure to follow something like:

```
id, event_name, event_start, event_end, user_id
```

That way when you write the delete row function you'll have the information you'll need to delete the appropriate record.

Comment: You haven't addresses any issues in his PHP code and introduced SQL injection vulnerability. Also this code will never execute!

Comment: You haven't fixed your answer even a little. You still concatenate SQL with PHP variables! Variables which do not even exists.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add at the end of the dataClick function in js file:

```
//AJAX function to comunicate to PHP script
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: your_url_php_script.php,
    data: {name:event_name, date: event_click.date},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
   dataType: json
});
```

Change a little the insert php function:

```
function insert($date, $name) {
  try {
    $conn = openConn();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name(date, name) VALUES (:date, :name)";

    $sql->bindParam(':date', $date);
    $sql->bindParam(':name', $name);

    $conn->exec($sql);

    return  "New Record Added";

  } catch(PDOException $exception) {
    return  $sql."<br>".$exception->getMessage();
  }
}
```

And also you need to add this to the end of your php script:

```
....

//Closes the door
function closeConn($conn)
{
  $conn = null;
}

$name= $_POST['name'];
$date  = $_POST['date'];

$query_result = insert($date, $name);

$result = array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'date' => $_POST['date'], 'message' =>$query_result);

//Always Return Encode the array into JSON for debuging
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

This code isn't tested